# Which will be loaded first static block or static variable?

Tags: java

As i read every one is saying static block will be executed first but when i run a piece of code i found that static variable is loading first.Now this is confusing me please give a proper explanation.

### Code

```
public class MyClass 
{
    static int x=show();
    static
    {
        System.out.println("Hello Mayar");
    }
    public static int show()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello Show");
        return 1;
    }
    public static void main(String a[])
    {
        System.out.println("Hello Main");
    }
}
```

### Output

```
Hello Show
Hello Mayar
Hello Main
```

Comment: *where* did you read that statement / claim?

Answer (score 7):

Static blocks and variables are evaluated in their order of appearance within the java source file.

As per [Java 8 spec on class initialization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2):

> 9. Next, execute either the class variable initializers and static initializers of the class, or the field initializers of the interface, in textual order, as though they were a single block.

Comment: Don't answer such [obvious duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15427747/476716).

Comment: apologies @OrangeDog !