# Why can you Initialize a static variable before declaring it

Tags: java, variables, static, static-variables, static-block

This code below will print out 5.

```
  static {
    x = 5;
  }
  static final int x;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(x);

  }
```

I don't understand how this is legal though. There are some other links, with no clear answer to why this works

[Which will be loaded first static variable or static block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15427747/which-will-be-loaded-first-static-variable-or-static-block?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Which will be loaded first static block or static variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46905888/which-will-be-loaded-first-static-block-or-static-variable?noredirect=1&lq=1)

because the answer I came across people saying were something in the lines of "static blocks are initialized in the order they appear in the source code."

But in this case, x = 5 comes before static final int x in the source code

Comment: Declarations are resolved at compile-time where as initialization is resolved at run-time.

Comment: The static variable is "declared" as part of class loading (it belongs to the class, not the instances), THEN the static blocks are executed. There is nothing unclear about this.

Comment: `static final int x` isn't executed at all. It's a declaration.

Comment: @JimGarrison Wrong, it not clear for many (beginners) people because it looks like it breaks the usual rule for block-scope variables: anything used should have been previously declared.

Comment: Thanks everyone, it makes sense now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary issue involved here is the difference between compiling your code and running it. The compiler ensures that all variables have been declared. Possibly it makes two passes over the abstract syntax tree, first to find all declarations, second to check all uses have a declaration.

Now when the code runs, variable declarations no longer matter because that was taken care of at compile time. The generated byte code performs the operations as defined in the Java source code.