# why I am getting ExceptionInInitializerError while acessing Hashmap from constructor which is initialized in static block

Tags: java

```
package test;

import java.util.HashMap;

class Check {
    private static Check check = new Check(); 
    private static HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    static{
        System.out.println("***********In static block***********");
        Check.map.put("1", "One");
        Check.map.put("2","Two");
    }
    private Check(){
        System.out.println("Map Contains "+map.get("1"));
    }

    public static Check getCheck() {
        return Check.check;
    }

}
public class CheckStatic{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Check.getCheck();
    }
}
```

I have created Singleton class which has static block. And in static block I have initialized hashmap and trying to access that in constructor of Singletion class.But I am getting exceptionInInitializerError. Please suggest what is am trying which is wrong...

Comment: If you want this to be a singleton, why don't you initialize the Map in your constructor of the singleton?
Your problem is actually in your constructor since this accesses the map and is first called in static code to initialize your singleton.
Doing initialization in your constructor will prevent those problems

Comment: @Matthias +1 and while on the subject, why make the map static in the first place. It should be a `private final` instance variable. But, since this may be just an excerpt of the total program, better not guess too far.

Comment: Also consider initialising the Map using an initialiser,
eg: `new HashMap<String, String>() {{`
  `put("1", "One");`
  `put("2", "Two");`
`}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class is initialized in the order of the declarations.  In your case this means:

```
private static Check check = new Check();
```

Is executed before:

```
private static HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

And therefore you get the error in the constructor because `map` has not been initialized.

Re-structure your class like this:

```
class Check 
{
  private static HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
  static
  {
    System.out.println("***********In static block***********");
    Check.map.put("1", "One");
    Check.map.put("2","Two");
  }

  private static Check check = new Check(); 

  private Check()
  {
    System.out.println("Map Contains "+map.get("1"));
  }

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the problem:

```
private static Check check = new Check();
```

and in the constructor you have

```
System.out.println("Map Contains "+map.get("1"));
```

So you've got a Catch-22 situation: you want the map to exist before the constructor has run, and you want the constructor to run before initializing the map.

All you need to do is put the declaration of the `check` singleton below the static initializer which sets up the map. At that point the constructor will be safe to run.

As a side note, make that `check` variable `final`. That's standard for singletons, and for a good reason: it guarantees that there will be only one instance.

Comment: Please suggest solution to avoid this.

Comment: Edited the answer. Basically, you just need to reorder your declaration so that the constructor call occurs after the static initializer block.

Answer (score 1):

The line `private static Check check = new Check();` runs the constructor which requires `map` (`map.get(1)`) whereas map is not yet created.

You may try to assign `check` at the end of your static block, when you are sure `map`exists.

I hope it helps.

```
private static Check check; 
private static HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
static{
    System.out.println("***********In static block***********");
    Check.map.put("1", "One");
    Check.map.put("2","Two");
    check = new Check(); // Now, maps exists, the ctr can use it.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You call the constructor, which uses the map, before the map is created and initialized. Initialize `check` after the `map` in the static block.

```
class Check {
    private static Check check; 
    private static HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    static{
        System.out.println("***********In static block***********");
        Check.map.put("1", "One");
        Check.map.put("2","Two");

        check = new Check();
    }
    private Check(){
        System.out.println("Map Contains "+map.get("1"));
    }

    public static Check getCheck() {
        return Check.check;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your map contains `null` value. You are trying to get `map.get("1")` the value from null. So only you got `exceptionInInitializerError` this Exception.

```
private static HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
private static Check check = new Check();
```

instead of

```
private static Check check = new Check();
private static HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your singleton instance of `Check` is created before `map` - therefore the latter is still `null` when `check`'s constructor is executed.

To fix that, just flip the order of the two static variables.

```
class Check {
    private static HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    private static Check check = new Check();
```

See also this question and answer: [Java : in what order are static final fields initialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446088/java-in-what-order-are-static-final-fields-initialized)