# final variable initialized first

Tags: java, static, initialization

I was reading the question here : [Java : in what order are static final fields initialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446088/java-in-what-order-are-static-final-fields-initialized)

According to the answer

> "except that final class variables and fields of interfaces whose
>   values are compile-time constants are initialized first ..."

I think this is not correct because the following will fail :

```
static {
    String y = x;
}

public static final String x = "test";
```

In the static block, `x` is not recognized. Can anyone please comment if that answer is correct ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of *initialization* doesn't change the fact that the JLS doesn't let you refer to variables before they're declared in various cases. This is described in [JLS§8.3.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.3):

> Use of class variables whose declarations appear textually after the use is sometimes restricted, even though these class variables are in scope (§6.3). Specifically, it is a compile-time error if all of the following are true:
>
> - The declaration of a class variable in a class or interface C appears textually after a use of the class variable;
> - The use is a simple name in either a class variable initializer of C or a static initializer of C;
> - The use is not on the left hand side of an assignment;
> - C is the innermost class or interface enclosing the use.

That's why your code gets this compilation erorr:

> error: illegal forward reference

The statement that static fields that are constant variables are initialized first is indeed defined in [JLS§12.4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2):

> 6. Otherwise, record the fact that initialization of the Class object for C is in progress by the current thread, and release LC.
>
>    Then, initialize the static fields of C which are constant variables (§4.12.4, §8.3.2, §9.3.1).
>
> ...
>
> 9. Next, execute either the class variable initializers and static initializers of the class, or the field initializers of the interface, in textual order, as though they were a single block.

As you can see, constant variables are initialized in step 6, but others in step 9.

This demonstrates the behavior:

```
public class Example {
    static String y;
    static  {
         y = foo();
    }

    static String foo() {
        return x.toUpperCase();
    }

    public static final String x = "test";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(y);
    }
}
```

That compiles, and outputs:

```
test
TEST
```

In contast, if you change the `x` line so it's not constant anymore:

```
public static final String x = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "test" : "ing";
```

It compiles, but then fails because `x` is `null` as of `y = foo();`.

---

For the avoidance of doubt: I **don't** recommend using methods to initialize fields like that. :-)

Comment: very nice example, I got confused how you could invoke static method inside the static block while the method is declared after , can you please explain that part ?

Comment: @MohammadKarmi - I probably should have defined it first just to avoid that question. :-D Nothing in the JLS prohibits that form of forward reference (referencing forward to a method rather than another field), so...it's allowed. I believe the prohibitions on forward references during initialization are to avoid possible cyclic situations (`String x = y; String y = x;`). That isn't an issue for methods, because they're part of the class and they exist once the class is loaded, before static initialization begins.

Comment: @MohammadKarmi Within static initializers, variables references must be topologically sorted, i.e. every initializer can only reference variables above it, not below it. This rule prevents cycles from forming (`String a = b; String b = a;`) On the other hand, methods can be declared and used in any order. The difference is that a declaration of a method doesn't "do" anything. If a method `a()` references a method `b()`, and `b()` references `a()`, it doesn't matter, because neither method is being invoked, only declared. Initializers are invoked immediately, so cycles are an issue.

Answer (score 1):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4446096/6252399) states:

> ... they are initialized in the order in which they appear in the source.

You are absolutely right, your example fails, because you are trying to use a variable that is declared after the usage. Since static block are executed in order of the source code, you are absolutely correct and should suggest and edit for that answer, because this statement is invalid:

> except that final class variables ... are initialized first.